# TV commercial depicting a vampire going up a manor using an elevator to reach a woman in a room. She hands him garlic and he takes a bite out of it

Tags: story-identification, tv, vampire

This is definitely a TV commercial I saw something like 25 years ago (around 2000s for sure), on one of the 5 most common French TV channels (TF1, France 2, France 3, France 5/Arte, M6). The commercial was entirely coloured (as in, not a black and white commercial).

I cannot remember which product it was supposed to advertise, but the premise depicted the inside of some kind of manor. The vampire entered an elevator to go up and reach a woman in a room. When she saw him approaching, she grabbed a bulb of garlic to defend herself, because [vampires hate garlic](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/VampiresHateGarlic) (warning: TV Tropes link).

However, as the woman was handing the garlic towards the vampire, instead of fearing it, he came closer, grabbed it, and the last scene I remember depicted him taking a bite out of it, as if it was an apple/a fruit.

What commercial could this premise possibly come from? I tried searching it on YouTube, but it looks like it wasn't posted there.

Comment: My guess is, it was a commercial for garlic.

Comment: @Spencer - Or breath mints :-)

Comment: https://www.enworld.org/threads/ads-that-you-like.158849/post-2766916 - Hesburger

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an advertisement for a coffee from the brand Nescafé; more specifically the "Nes Fusion" coffee.

https://www.ina.fr/ina-eclaire-actu/publicite/pub2452447067/nescafe-nes-nesfusion-le-vampire-version-39-secondes

The vampire wakes up from his slumber and picks up a coat that his assistant gives him, before proceeding down a corridor.

[image: A frame of the vampire proceeding down a corridor after putting on his coat.]

Meanwhile, a woman who was sleeping in a big white bed suddenly wakes up, as if she was aware something was about to happen.

The vampire heads into an elevator which starts going up. Once it reaches its destination, he walks out.

[image: The elevator's gate open up, and the vampire proceeds towards his destination.]

At the same time, the woman grabs a garlic bulb. Apparently she had an entire bowl filled with it next to her bed; maybe she was prepared for the eventuality the vampire would come for her.

[image: The woman can be seen grabbing a bulb of garlic, out of an entire bowl filled with garlic.]

As the vampire pushes open the door to the woman's room and approaches her, she points the grabbed garlic bulb towards him.

[image: The woman, still in her bed, points the garlic bulb towards the vampire as he crosses the door into her room. This point of view is from behind the woman, allowing us to see the vampire walking in.]
[image: Same as the image from above, but this time the point of view is from behind the vampire walking towards the woman.]

But to her shock, he comes closer, grabs it, then proceeds to bite it.

[image: The shocked woman watches as the vampire takes the garlic bulb out of her hand.]
[image: A close-up frame of the vampire about to take a bite out of the garlic bulb.]

Then the following text is displayed:

[image: A text is displayed in French. It says: "Préparez-vous à aimer ce que vous n'avez jamais aimé."]

In means something in the line of: get ready to love things you've never loved before.

The rest of the advertisement is about a coffee for people who don't like the taste of coffee, as the vampire proceeds to open the window's blind, exposing himself to the sun, and then the woman shows him her neck as he proceeds to bite her.

Comment: Quite a convoluted advertisement. I would have never guessed this was about coffee.

Comment: Barista, one double garlic latte _sil vous plait_, with extra olive oil.

Comment: Just in case: I'd like to point out that I am not affiliated with Nestlé in any way whatsoever. This is just an advertisement I have been trying to find for a few months, ever since I remembered it during a random daydreaming.

Comment: Purely out of curiosity, how did you find it?

Comment: @Jenayah My initial attempts at searching for "vampire advertisement garlic" didn't lead anywhere. Eventually, I remembered having found an old "Pitch Pasquier" advertisement on the website "ina", on which I also found some very old "Santa Klaus phone number" advertisement which also didn't exist anywhere else. So I tried searching "advertisement vampire garlic" on ina, which didn't show any result. In desperation (kind of), I searched "vampire" and started scrolling down in the hope that I would eventually find something.

Comment: Nice thinking of INA! I was searching on CulturePub myself and kept running on the same Boursin commercial (garlic cheese) :p